# MongoDB/Mongoose querying subdocuments and indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Ok, so I am new to MongoDB and the world of document based databases. I have stored in MongoDB a collection of profiles which has two subdocuments; 'Interest' and 'Country'. Below is schema information:

```
var Country = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    countryCode: String
});

var Interest = new mongoose.Schema({
    label: {
        type: String
    }
});

var Profile = connection.model('profile', {
    uid: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true
    },
    username: String
    country: Country,
    interests: [Interest],
    member_since: Date
});
```

***Let's say I want to be able to run a fast and efficient query*** such that I can select all of the users interested in 'music' and whose countryCode is 'AU' but done in an efficient way that doesn't scan all documents (I'm guessing I need an index?), how can I do this? Below is a sample profile as it appears in Compass:

```
_id:59d17efa3ed3a453e2b865f9
username:"Rudolph"
country:Object
  name: "Australia"
  countryCode:"AU"
  _id:59d17efa3ed3a453e2b865fa
__v:0
interests:Object
  label:Array
    0:"music"
    1:"film"
    2:"dance"
member_since:2017-10-01 19:49:14.565
```